# Mantel Haenszel stratified estimates in survival data in R?

Tags: r, survival-analysis, survival

I've got survival data with an outcome, an exposure, and a variable I'd like to stratify on but can't find a function to perform Mantel-Haenszel rate ratio. For example with the `lung` dataset from `survival` I'd like to look at the outcome of `status` based on `sex` but stratified by age. I've set up age brackets with

```
library(tidyverse)
library(survival)

lung2 <- lung %>%
    mutate(agecat = as.factor(case_when(age < 50 ~ 0,
                                        age < 70 ~ 1,
                                        age >= 70 ~ 2)))
```

`epi.2by2` from `epiR` gets me close with

```
library(epiR)

epi.2by2(table(as.factor(lung2$status),
               as.factor(lung2$sex),
               lung2$agecat), 
         method = "cohort.count")
#>              Outcome +    Outcome -      Total        Inc risk *        Odds
#> Exposed +           26           37         63              41.3       0.703
#> Exposed -          112           53        165              67.9       2.113
#> Total              138           90        228              60.5       1.533
#> 
#> 
#> Point estimates and 95% CIs:
#> -------------------------------------------------------------------
#> Inc risk ratio (crude)                         0.61 (0.44, 0.83)
#> Inc risk ratio (M-H)                           0.61 (0.45, 0.84)
#> Inc risk ratio (crude:M-H)                     0.99
#> Odds ratio (crude)                             0.33 (0.18, 0.61)
#> Odds ratio (M-H)                               0.34 (0.19, 0.63)
#> Odds ratio (crude:M-H)                         0.97
#> Attrib risk in the exposed (crude) *           -26.61 (-40.70, -12.52)
#> Attrib risk in the exposed (M-H) *             -25.88 (-42.58, -9.19)
#> Attrib risk (crude:M-H)                        1.03
#> -------------------------------------------------------------------
#>  M-H test of homogeneity of PRs: chi2(2) = 0.191 Pr>chi2 = 0.909
#>  M-H test of homogeneity of ORs: chi2(2) = 0.394 Pr>chi2 = 0.821
#>  Test that M-H adjusted OR = 1:  chi2(1) = 12.299 Pr>chi2 = <0.001
#>  Wald confidence limits
#>  M-H: Mantel-Haenszel; CI: confidence interval
#>  * Outcomes per 100 population units
```

But it doesn't take time to event data (rates) into consideration. It has a `method = "cohort.time"` option, but I can't seem to get it to work. Ultimately the output I'd like would be similar to STATAs `stmh sex, by(agecat)` which would give risk ratio estimates for each strata with upper and lower 95% confidence interval as well as overall estimate for risk ratio with chi-square and p-value. `mhor` from `epiDisplay` gives output close to what I'm looking for

```
library(epiDisplay)
mhor(lung2$status,
    lung2$sex,
    lung2$agecat, design = "cohort",
     graph = FALSE)
#> 
#> Stratified analysis by  Var3 
#>                 OR lower lim. upper lim.  P value
#> Var3 0       0.476     0.0532      3.786 0.653417
#> Var3 1       0.363     0.1642      0.788 0.006387
#> Var3 2       0.243     0.0424      1.222 0.060217
#> M-H combined 0.344     0.1880      0.631 0.000453
#> 
#> M-H Chi2(1) = 12.3 , P value = 0 
#> Homogeneity test, chi-squared 2 d.f. = 0.38 , P value = 0.828
```

but it only gives odds ratios and not rate ratios.

Comment: are you looking for `?survdiff`

Comment: Survdiff tests for a stratified difference, but doesn't give the adjusted rate ratios

Comment: You can consider in a sense the odds ratio as risk ratio, provided that the probability of the disease in the population is rare. The odds ratio is in that case almost
identical to the risk ratio. [Here](https://ncss-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/themes/ncss/pdf/Procedures/NCSS/Mantel-Haenszel_Test.pdf) you find some more details.

Comment: Yeah, I realize the statistical implications, but what I'm trying to do is convert some code from STATA to R and keep the output as similar as possible, so this is more of a technical question than a statistical question.